# Debug ASP.NET application using remote IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2012, remote-debugging

I'm developing ASP.NET applications using Visual Studio 2012. I've always used IIS express to test application while developing, but now I need to test it on production environment.

IIS is running on a remote server, I installed there the Remote Debugger studio, created an application under default site (\test\baseTest), created a test project in Visual Studio 2012 and set to "Use Custom Web Server" at path `http://myServerName/test/baseTest/`.

Ok, there we are, I press F5 to start debugging, the connection through debugger works correctly (I can see a new line saying "myDomain\myuserName connected" but... the application is void, I miss all .aspx files.

[image]

Am i missing something? Should I set some parameters in Visual Studio to deploy all file when debugging to remote site?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is remote debugging not automatic deployment.

You should copy all the website files to the remote iis.
Remember to build in debug and deploy all the .pdb files.
Check also in web.config.

```
<system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" />
</system.web>
```

Launch the Remote Debugging Monitor (msvsmon.exe) when you start debugging

There you can find a comprehensive guide to remote debugging:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38132/Remote-IIS-Debugging-Debug-your-ASP-NET-Applicatio

Comment: `<compilation debug="true" />` is already set on config file.
Should I really manually copy those files each time? It's not very handly... isn't there a way to automatically copy file when debug starts?

Comment: @LorenzoC remote debugging is intended to analyze strange behavior of production servers. It is not to use a remote server as development enviroment. Maybe you can create a batch script in postbuildevents to copy files...

Comment: so what con I do to test "on the fly" my code, assuming that I don't have a local IIS and IIS express it's not ok because I need to interact with AD (and it can be done only from specific servers)? Do I need to publish application each time to a test site on the remote server?

Comment: @LorenzoC sorry but I think you have no option... anyway it is easy to install IIS. Do you use ftp or have a shared folder on the remote server?

Comment: Yes. Do you think that using that remote folder to place my project is a good solution? It would be easy to set up a test site.

Comment: @LorenzoC I think it should work but it is not a best practice :D

Comment: It works, thank you, you have been really helpful! I'm not sure this is the best way, but at least I can go on

Answer (score -2):

To debug asp.net application from IIS you need to attach w3wp.exe process by going to Tools->Attach to Process option. You can see the detailed steps of debugging using IIS with diagram on this link: [Debug asp.net application using IIS](https://web.archive.org/web/20170202075845/http://www.brainbrushups.com/2014/08/debug-aspnet-website-or-project-using.html)